# Pass dictionary of variable bindings to selector

Tags: ios, uitextfield, selector

I was wondering if you could do something like this:

```
[self.verificationCodeField addTarget:self
            action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:)
  forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
  [self.verificationCodeField1 addTarget:self
                action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
  [self.verificationCodeField2 addTarget:self
                action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
  [self.verificationCodeField3 addTarget:self
                action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
  [self.verificationCodeField4 addTarget:self
                action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

in a more efficient way. I tried to group them into variable bindings like so:

```
NSDictionary *dictWithAllTheTextFields = 
NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(self.verificationCodeField,
self.verificationCodeField1,self.
verificationCodeField2,
self.verificationCodeField3,
self.verificationCodeField4);
```

And then pass the entire group to the selector, but that didn't work either.

Nor did this work:

```
  for(UITextField *textField in dictWithAllTheTextFields){
    [textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:)
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
  }
```

What is the most efficient way for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a dictionary as an array will do:

```
NSArray *textFields = @[
    self.verificationCodeField,
    self.verificationCodeField1,
    self.verificationCodeField2,
    self.verificationCodeField3,
    self.verificationCodeField4
];
```

and then your code will work:

```
for (UITextField *textField in textFields) {
    [textField addTarget:self
                  action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
}
```